# how is possible? Buyers Can Checkout Without a PayPal Account

Tags: api, paypal, payment

How is possible? Buyers Can Checkout Without a PayPal Account. Customers enter their name and shipping address.
They’re prompted for their credit card, email address, and phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "Guest Checkout".  If you want to force that option you will need to use the Express Checkout APIs.  Then you can add some specific parameters to ensure the guest checkout option is always prominently displayed.

Guest Checkout works with Standard Payments buttons too, but it is cookie based with Standard.  As such, if anybody at any time has logged in to a PayPal account on the browser currently in use, the system will assume they are going to log again and sort of buries the guest checkout option.

Again, Express Checkout won't do that, and it's the #1 reason I get contacted by people about upgrading to Express Checkout.